# How is the accumulator parameter sent to the function?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In the following code I am unable to understand how the accumulator parameters are sent.

```
meanFold :: [Double] -> Double
meanFold l = (foldr op unit l) 0 0
    where
        unit :: Double -> Double -> Double
        unit n sum = sum / n
        op :: Double -> (Double ->Double ->Double) -> (Double -> Double -> Double)
        (x `op` y ) n sum = y (n+1) (sum +x)
```

I understand that foldr will firstly apply the operator `op` for the last element in the list l and the unit which I've selected ( which would be the function "unit" ). 
But how are the accumulator parameters of meanFold sent to the unit function so that sum and n are initially 0?

Comment: Personally, I consider "calling `foldr` with more than 3 arguments" a Haskell antipattern, even if some haskellers apparently like that style. It isn't an horribly bad antipattern, but in such cases, I'd rather use explicit recursion, which is easier to read.

Comment: I completely agree. This implementation is only for educational purposes. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: @chi I'd write it that way in any case I want to participate in fusion. That's not a trivial improvement in the good cases.

Comment: In this particular case though I wouldn't say it's a case of `foldr` vs "explicit recursion though". The `foldr` is calculating a function `\n s ->  (sum xs + s) / (length xs + n)` to then obtain `(sum xs) / (length xs)` via application to zeros. That's just not a very sensible thing to do. Essentially what it computes is `(sum xs, length xs)` and it would simpler to implement the fold so it returns that pair and then do the division.

Comment: @JorgeAdriano Agreed, but I'd use `foldl'` to compute the pair `(sum xs, length xs)` since `foldr` would be inefficient for that.

Comment: @chi sure I meant in terms of clarity only. For efficiency I think even `foldl'` alone isn't enough since pairs aren't strict.

Comment: @JorgeAdriano One can always use `foldl' (\ (!s,!len) x -> (s+x, len+1)) (0,0) xs` which should run in constant space. Alternatively, force the pair components before constructing the pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand that foldr will firstly apply the operator op for the last element in the list

I'm not completely sure you are understanding that bit either. Firstly lets look at the type of `foldr` (specialised to lists) and its definition.

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f e []     = e 
foldr f e (x:xs) = f x (foldr f xs)
```

The `a` in this case is `Double` and `b` is `Double -> Double -> Double`. The former you know it's `Double` because you are folding a list of doubles. The latter is the type of `unit`, which is what you return in the empty case.

So what your `foldr` is doing is calculating a function of type `Double -> Double -> Double` from a list of doubles. In the empty case you simply return the function,

```
unit n sum = sum / n
```

which is the function that divides its second argument for the first. That is (/) but with its arguments swapped. In each step of the fold you modify that binary function using an element of the list. You modify it via `op`

```
op :: Double -> (Double ->Double ->Double) -> (Double -> Double -> Double)
(x `op` y ) n sum = y (n+1) (sum +x)
```

I really dislike the letter `y` there as it makes it look like a double. Let's rewrite that as an `h`. And lets abstract over `n` and `sum` too, using a lambda to make it easier to understand what's going on.

```
op :: Double -> (Double ->Double ->Double) -> (Double -> Double -> Double)
(x `op` h) = \n sum -> h (n+1) (sum +x)
```

So given a double value `x` from the list, and a binary function `h` calculated thus far (which initially is `unit`) we are going calculate a new function,

```
\n sum -> h (n+1) (sum+x)
```

which is just like the previous function `h` except it sums `1` to the first argument and `x` to the second before applying `h`.

So in the end for a list `[x1, x2, x3]` that fold will return the function,

```
\n sum -> (x1+x2+x3+sum) / (1+1+1+n)
```

And when you apply that to the two zeros you get,

```
  (\n sum -> (x1+x2+x3+sum) / (1+1+1+n)) 0 0 
= (x1+x2+x3+0) / (1+1+1+0)
= (x1+x2+x3) / (1+1+1)
```

Answer (score 3):

`foldr` will apply the function still from the beginning to the end of the collection, not in any reverse order.

The definition of `foldr` gives you insight in how it works. Key difference to `foldl` is the order of parentheses.

[More details here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27)

Comment: I meant that it firstly evaluates the operation `op` on last element of the list  `l` and the `unit` which I've supplied. The question is related to how the accumulator parameters are sent to `unit` .

Comment: No, it first evaluates op on the first element, and the result from the recursive call.  If the op ignores its second argument the recursive call never happens.

Comment: @Eduard6421 You are thinking that in, say, `f x (f y z)` we start from evaluating `f y z` but this is not correct. That would be the case in an eager language, but in a lazy language we really start from the first call to `f` passing `x` and a thunk representing an unevaluated `f y z`.